# How do i load a different template for different users screen width

Tags: templates

How can i load different templates for different screen sizes.Or is there some other method that  i load different html for different screen size.

Please help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Don't load scripts if on mobile/tablet](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166086/dont-load-scripts-if-on-mobile-tablet)

Comment: See my answer for the dpossible duplicate. Same applies here

Comment: If your goal is to size your site appropriately for the user's device, you will find the information you want searching for "responsive design".  This is accomplished with media queries in CSS.  If you truly wish to serve different HTML then that is a very difficult challenge.

Comment: @Pieter Goosen , i saw your answer, but it is for the scripts. What i wish is to load a totally different template . I am developing a theme for news agency. And you know a totally different template is required when viewed on tablet or laptop than when viewed on mobile device.Mobile devices need the sites to be like especially for a news website.     Right now what i am doing is hiding the html/content for mobile devices, but still the content is being transferred which increases overhead . what i need is when the request comes to server for the first time is there a way to know the size

Comment: The same applies for loading templates, not just scripts. There are no way for wordpress to know a screen size. As said in my answer, you only have `wp_is_mobile()` which only detect mobile phones. You can either try to use jquery or media queries in css as a work around.

Comment: @Pieter Goosen Thamks a lot!!! wp_is_mobile solves my problem, as i wanted to load different template (app like ) only for the mobile devices. For rest of devices like tab they can handle the same template.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen width through JavaScript or jQuery, please check out the answer to the similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180134/how-to-get-users-screen-resolution-with-php)..