# Faster fonts on mobile

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style, responsive

I think I have a great idea to make my site load faster in mobile: *"don't load the custom fonts in small screens"*

I know how to style/change the font used depending on screen size with media queries and css.
What I don't know is how to prevent the custom fonts from loading in small screens.
I use google fonts and I enqueue them in functions.php, but I'm open to your workarounds.

Btw, this how to do it, [when using @font](https://css-tricks.com/preventing-the-performance-hit-from-custom-fonts/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function to detect mobile and handheld devices. You can use that to define your enqueue  function to load fonts conditionally.

You can enqueue fonts for non mobile devices like this.

```
function my_enqueue_function() {

  if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'gfonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arbutus+Slab', false, NULL, 'all' );

  }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_function' );
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any experience of this code in action? Does it work as it should/expected?

Comment: Yes. It works great. Used it on couple of projects. The only downside you might experience is that this function `wp_is_mobile()` does not differentiate between mobile and tablets. It considers both the same. In your case, this might not be a huge problem but on a project where you want to only target tablets, it will not work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this (partial?) solution:

Use wp_is_mobile() when you enqueue your fonts, like this:

```
function my_scripts() {
    // Load if not mobile
    if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) {
         wp_enqueue_style( 'my-google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nicefont:400,500' );
    }
    // your other scripts that you enqueue...
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

references:
[codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) and [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166086/dont-load-scripts-if-on-mobile-tablet)

There is also this [plug-in](https://github.com/scottsweb/mobble), but I think it is overkill for my requirements.

Comment: Cool so you also found it. :)